# Sleuth: transcripts with beta close to 0 are considered differentially expressed in a likelihood-ratio test

Tags: rna-seq, differential-expression

I'm comparing the results that I obtain when doing a DE analysis with the Wald test and the likelihood-ratio test. One the thing that I've noticed is that there are many genes with 'beta' close to zero that are considered differentially expressed between the conditions.

I know that the likelihood-ratio test does't use the beta values to calculate the p-values, but I find it strange that transcripts with similar expression values between the conditions are being considered differentially expressed.

**Volcano plot (Wald test q-values):**
[image]

**Volcano plot (likelihood-ratio test q-values):**
[image]

Comment: I’ve never used Sleuth but there are several odd things about this data as far as I’m concerned: the y-axis on the Wald test plot for instance seems way off (inflated). The q-values in the LR plot are a lot more reasonable.

Comment: Cross-posted [on biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/267498/#267637) and the [kallisto mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kallisto-sleuth-users/bRb4nRhoZZw).

Comment: What does this look like if you plot Beta vs average TPM across all samples, excluding those with qval < 0.05?

Comment: What is the actual question? Why are some genes with beta = 0 and qvalue < 0.05?

Comment: Yes, that's the thing I can't understand

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered [here](https://github.com/pachterlab/sleuth/issues/140)

Comment: Could you post here also the solution to your problem? Just to avoid having to chase the anser from site to site